# Google Text To Speech APIの単語別の発音調整

Tags: google-api

Google Text To Speech APIをWave Netを使い利用し、日本語のテキストファイル（SSMLファイルに変換の上）を音声に変換し、日本語の音声を取得できました。

概ね良好なのですが、ところどころ、単語の発音がおかしいため、音程や発音を調整しようとしたのですが、ファイル単位で調整する方法しか見出せず、単語別に発音/音程を調整することができません。

レファレンスを参考に調整をトライしたのですが、解決策を見いだせておりません。
[GCP Text To Speech | SSML レファレンス](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml?hl=ja)

Text-To-Speechの出力前に微妙な発音や音程を単語別に調整する方法はあるでしょうか？　ご存じの方がいらっしゃったら教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/244456